# Heart equation with a radius of $r$

Tags: analysis, functions

The following is the heart equation with a radius of 1 according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_symbol#Mathematical_description)

$$(x^2 + y^2 − 1)^3 − x^2y^3 = 0.$$

What would be the general formula with a radius of $r$?

Comment: By just trying out values $(x^2 + y^2 -r^2)^3 - rx^2 y^2=0$

Comment: Just scale $x \to x/r$ and $y \to y/r$.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi it is not working

Comment: @edkeveked I actually meant y cubed at the end of the equation, here is a demonstration. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5y1axaphre

Comment: Thanks @AnindyaPrithvi . Does the inner part of the heart satisfy the equation: $$(x^2 + y^2 − r^2)^3 − rx^2y^3 < 0.$$ You can have a look at what I am trying to do here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66034150/tensorflow-js-drawing-heart-using-webgl